# Media Query Solution

Tags: css, media-queries

There is a problem when I'm using a background image for the header. The header height is 100vh and the image is displaying fine in computers and landscape devices. But when I view it on portrait devices or screens the background gets messy. My real question is:

> Is there a way to display different images for landscape and portrait
>   screens?

Comment: What about uising Media queries?

Comment: That's What I asked? How to use media query in that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the [orientation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#orientation) media query.

```
@media all and (orientation: portrait) { ... }

@media all and (orientation: landscape) { ... }
```

Of course you can just use media queries the regular way, but by using SASS (and probably LESS), you can change how your class works in different orientations by doing something like:

```
.my-class {
    background: [normal background]; // assuming the default is portrait
    @media all and (orientation: landscape) { 
        // override for landscape
        background: [landscape background];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude! Helped A Lot! I will try for the next project.